# hibernet and spring data jpa version compatible with oracle 10g database

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, oracle10g

I am trying to build a spring boot project and I have orcale 10g in my system and also I have java 19 . so which hibernet version and spring data jpa version are supported ?

I tried with hibernet latest version and It says It could not find oracle dialect and I have used oracle 10 g dialect

Comment: Can you share your configuration and error you received?

Comment: Thank you for your time , I managed to solve the error .